# Finding the 2 rows where a given value sits between 2 values in a table

Tags: sql-server

I need to find 2 values and related columns where a given number either sits between the column values or is either of the 2 values.  Really confusing but here is a table:

I have a car_id 2 which is going at speed 12 and I want to get a fuel value.  I need to get the value of the next higher and the next lower and use those to calculate the fuel for speed 12 for car_id 2.  ids are not in any useful order and speed is not always incremental.  I have a stored procedure which passes the values of car_id and speed and delivers the value after a calculation but I would like to just use a query or build a view which can perform this function too.

| id | car_id | speed | fuel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 10 | 20 |
| 3 | 1 | 15 | 29 |
| 4 | 1 | 20 | 37 |
| 5 | 1 | 25 | 45 |
| 6 | 2 | 5 | 7 |
| 7 | 2 | 10 | 14 |
| 8 | 2 | 15 | 20 |
| 9 | 2 | 20 | 26 |
| 10 | 2 | 25 | 31 |

Hope I haven't confused you too much and thank you for your help.

Comment: What are the expected results for your (presumably) sample data? What have you tried that's not working?

Comment: Hi Stu, I was just going to write that :)..  I am expecting to get row id 2 and 3 as the speed 12 is between these values and then use the speed and fuel columns for both rows to work out the fuel for the speed value 12 which is 22 rounded I believe.  As it is sample data.

Comment: sorry no punctuation :)

Comment: There is an *edit* option - you also have the chance to preview your question before you publish it, why would you publish it unfinished?

Comment: fair point but at the time I thought there was enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #data;
CREATE TABLE #data
(
    id INT,
    car_id INT,
    speed INT,
    fuel INT
);

INSERT INTO #data
VALUES
(1  ,1, 5   ,10),
(2  ,1, 10  ,20),
(3  ,1, 15  ,29),
(4  ,1, 20  ,37),
(5  ,1, 25  ,45),
(6  ,2, 5   , 7),
(7  ,2, 10  ,14),
(8  ,2, 15  ,20),
(9  ,2, 20  ,26),
(10 ,2, 25  ,31);

DECLARE @speed INT = 12;
DECLARE @car_id INT = 2;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT speed, 
        fuel, 
        LEAD(speed,1) OVER (PARTITION BY car_id ORDER BY speed) speed2,
        LEAD(fuel,1)  OVER (PARTITION BY car_id ORDER BY speed) fuel2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY car_id ORDER BY speed) rn
    FROM #data
    WHERE car_id = @car_id
), rts AS 
(
    SELECT MAX(rn) rowtoselect
    FROM cte 
    WHERE cte.speed <= @speed
)
SELECT cte.speed, cte.fuel, cte.speed2, cte.fuel2
FROM cte 
INNER JOIN rts ON cte.rn = rts.rowtoselect
```

Comment: Thank you James.  I was so close but I need to work more on my partition queries.  Thank you, I now have my values.  Many thanks.